# xeCJK and quotation marks

Tags: xecjk, chinese

In a document mostly in English and Sanskrit, I would like to display a few short strings in Chinese, a language apparently not supported by polyglossia, which I normally use for language switching commands. It appears that the xeCJK package is the recommended option for that. However, it seems to be messing up quotation marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Droid Sans Fallback}
\begin{document}
“test” ``test''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, this is probably a feature I don't understand, but the documentation is in Chinese. I wonder if it can be disabled? I would rather not want to switch back all my quotation marks to ``` `` ``` and `''`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272790/xecjk-breaks-non-chinese-characters/272797#272797 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36878/xecjk-messes-with-punctuation/36896#36896 may help.

Comment: Try ``\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{Default}{`“,`”}``.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks muzimuzhi Z !!!